# Does wireshark support web frontend?

Tags: wireshark

I'm looking for a wireshark web front end that can diplay the content of a pcap file in the similar way as wireshark . The purpose of doing it is that we can setup a pcap repository for certain protocol that can be shared between a develop team .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark can export to PSML and PDML formats, which are XML-based so you may be able to transform them into a HTML document.

See:

- http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html#ChIOExportPSMLDialog
- http://www.nbee.org/doku.php?id=netpdl:psml_specification

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap#Wrappers_for_use_of_libpcap.2FWinPcap_in_languages_other_than_C_and_C.2B.2B) lists wrappers for several scripting languages. You should be able to put such an application together relatively easily.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Wireshark to read pcap file. That's not an answer to your question, but you could consider to just offer the pcap files by your web front end.

The advantage would be that Wireshark has a lot of anylsis tools that you will not want to reimplent in your web front end.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge. However you can use `xpra` to forward any X11 app into the browser. This acts more like "remote desktop" than a "web app" and it is not suitable for more than 1 user at a time.

https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra-html5